# Is there a USB Host Controllers on iPads?

Tags: usb, ipad

Edit after topic is put on hold :

Does iPads have a USB Host controller? I guess, there is none, because they dont have a USB port.

Generally speaking, does the USB Host controller needs to be active all the time, to detect a insertion of a USB device and hence might not be a good idea for tablets / iPads?

Comment: USB devices can connect to an iPad: https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK0W2AM . A power adapter is needed for higher-power USB devices.

Comment: mobile devices are off-topic here, except in how to interface with computers.

Comment: @infoclogged it actually should be in askdifferent

Comment: @Keltari It was closed as off-topic at Ask Different. Though I don't see why it's off-topic there; you should raise a meta question there about it.

Comment: @gparyani I can read.  However, it is ON topic there

Comment: Edit - upon further review - this is off-topic - per our MSU thread here: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5045/please-vote-on-proposed-changes-to-our-policy-on-tablet-computers . Thanks to @Mokubai for reminding me of this.

Comment: I accidentally VTC as off-topic, oh well. I meant to vote as primarily opinion-based. Because that’s what it is. It’s a design decision Apple made.

Comment: @DanielB Its iffy.  The question is asking why there isnt a USB host controller, which is an opinion.  But the reality is that it does have one...  so the answer contains a factual correction... plus an opinion xD

Comment: @Keltari Well, looking past these technical inaccuracies, the question in the title is still very valid, though opinion-based.

Comment: Tablets, such as Andoid tablets and iPads, [are off-topic here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3266/should-tablet-computer-questions-be-allowed-on-super-user) and already have appropriate homes in [apple.se] and [android.se]. A Surface Pro is a "real" computer in tablet form. This question is basically asking for the design decision around some technical situation and can only be answered by the people who designed it. It is either off-topic as opinion-based, or just plain off-topic.

Comment: For iPads? [Apple.se].

Comment: @infoclogged because according to their help they don't want opinion based questions such as "[Asking how/why Apple does <some thing XYZ>](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)".  It's not the sort of question we really want either I'm afraid as no one except those who were intimately involved in the design of a product can say for sure why decisions were made.

Comment: Otherwise, ask on their meta why it was closed.

Comment: "The technology" is intimately related to "their design". They made design decisions that dictated the technology they chose or ignored. They **chose**, for whatever reasons, to make it that way. You are asking about a technical point about a choice that some human made. The technology is there and for whatever reasons they **chose** not to do it. That makes this question opinion based. The fact that one (off-topic here btw) device doesn't have the ability while another does is completely down to ***design decisions***.

Comment: @infoclogged Question like “which FTP client is the best” are clearly opinion-based. Questions pertaining to design decisions are harder to tell apart. However, in this case, we know it’s not a technical limitation. In fact, iPads (and many other tablets and phones, keyword USB OTG) support acting as a USB host. So it must be a pure design decision and as such is opinion-based.

Comment: @Mokubai can you please delete this question, because on one hand, I cannot delete this closed question and on the other hand, someone is downovting after it has already been put on hold.

Comment: The rules for question deletion are in the [help]: https://superuser.com/help/deleted-questions Essentially though while you have downvotes an answer has upvotes.  To delete your question they would lose reputation. If they agree to the reputation loss then I will gladly delete it for you but until then please do not deface your question.

Comment: @Mokubai I have edited this question. Maybe it more understandable now and you can unhold it? If there is anything yet to be edited, please guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The iPad *does* have a USB host controller built in it.  However, there are no USB ports, only the one Apple Lightning port.  The Apple Lightning port and cable are USB compatible, however they also contain more connections for more data.  This means you cant plug in a standard USB cable.  There are Lightning peripherals that you can plug in, such as this [keyboard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JXPGX04).

So why doesnt Apple use standard USB?  Well you would have to ask them.

However, the ability to plug in any USB device means you need to *support* those devices, which is a lot of work.  And considering a tablet is supposed to be a simple device, it isnt necessary.

Thats why comparing it to a MS Surface is flawed.  The Surface is a full computer with a desktop OS.

Comment: Why did the original-model Surface and Surface 2, which were intended as basic tablets, have it? Also, I recently got an LG Android tablet, which has a USB port.

Comment: @gparyani Those models were still running a full desktop OS.  Granted it was Windows RT, which was a failure.  As long as MS or the USB peripheral manufacturer provided a driver, the port was full functional.

Comment: as far as I have read, the USB Host controllers needs to be active all the time and hence drains down the battery. And since iPads are USB Slaves, it is inefficient to put both master and slave on one. Am I right?

Comment: @infoclogged you keep saying master/slave which is just wrong.  As stated in my answer, The iPad is a peripheral device AND a USB host controller.  As stated in my answer you CAN plug in Lightning based USB devices.  Said devices do draw power from the iPad.

Comment: @infoclogged and Keltari, actually, iPad(s) (and many other small tablet-computers) are either DEVICE **or** HOST, not "AND". This is called Dual-Role Data device. If nothing is connected, both HOST Controller and DEVICE controller are in deep sleep state, so the "efficiency" is not a concern. If a cable is connected, one of controllers wakes up depending on connect information. I don't know details of Lightening port, but Type-C does this through CC channel.